# Animated Matplotlib Plot in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, tkinter

I'm really struggling with an live Plot using FuncAnimation and Tkinter. I'm not sure what info is needed to reproduce the problem. Please forgive me if anything is missing.
In a stripped down version it works fine:

```
from numpy.random import normal
from numpy import exp
def fn(x):
    A=3e-8
    B=6e3
    Inoise = 1e-10
    if x == 0:
        I = Inoise
    elif A*x**2*exp(-B/x) < Inoise:
        I = Inoise
    else:
        I = A*x**2*exp(-B/x)
    return normal(1,0.4,1)[0]*I

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.pyplot import Figure
from tkinter import Frame

from queue import Queue
class LivePlotWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master,xlabel='',ylabel='',logx=False,logy=False):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=1)     
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)   
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.xlabel = xlabel
        self.ylabel = ylabel
        self.logx = logx
        self.logy = logy
        self.q = Queue()
        self._axini()

    def _axini(self):
        self.ax.cla()
        self.ax.set_xlabel(self.xlabel)
        self.ax.set_ylabel(self.ylabel)
        if self.logx==True:
            self.ax.set_xscale('log', nonposx='clip')
        if self.logy==True:
            self.ax.set_yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
        self.fig.tight_layout()

    def _update(self,i):
        print(i)
        [x,y] = self.q.get(block=True) 
        print([x,y])
        self.ax.plot(x,y,'b.')  # update the data

    def run(self,ncalls):
        self._axini()
        print(ncalls)   
        self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.fig, self._update, range(ncalls-1), interval=100, repeat=False)
        print(ncalls)

    def addP(self,x,y):
        self.q.put([x,y])

    def stop(self):
        self.ani.event_source.stop()

from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.title('Kennlinien-Messprogramm')
root.geometry('700x500')
plot = LivePlotWindow(root,'Voltage in V','Current in A',logy=True)

n=100
plot.run(n)
for i in range(n):
    plot.addP(i*10,fn(i*10))
root.mainloop()
```

But when I'm integrating it in a GUI with menu, its just not calling the animation function. It seems when I pass my Plot object as a command call its not working anymore? If I call the start function directly it wortks. I have no idea why:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.pyplot import Figure
from tkinter import Tk,Frame,Menu

from queue import Queue
class LivePlotWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master,xlabel='',ylabel='',logx=False,logy=False):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=1)     
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)   
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.xlabel = xlabel
        self.ylabel = ylabel
        self.logx = logx
        self.logy = logy
        self.q = Queue()
        self._axini()

    def _axini(self):
        self.ax.cla()
        self.ax.set_xlabel(self.xlabel)
        self.ax.set_ylabel(self.ylabel)
        if self.logx==True:
            self.ax.set_xscale('log', nonposx='clip')
        if self.logy==True:
            self.ax.set_yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
        self.fig.tight_layout()

    def _update(self,i):
        print(i)
        [x,y] = self.q.get(block=True) 
        print([x,y])
        self.ax.plot(x,y,'b.')  # update the data

    def run(self,ncalls):
        self._axini()
        print(ncalls)   
        self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.fig, self._update, range(ncalls-1), interval=100, repeat=False)
        print(ncalls)

    def addP(self,x,y):
        self.q.put([x,y])

    def stop(self):
        self.ani.event_source.stop()

from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.title('Kennlinien-Messprogramm')
root.geometry('700x500')
plot = LivePlotWindow(root,'Voltage in V','Current in A',logy=True)

def start(menu,plot):
    menu.entryconfig('\u25B6', state='disabled')
    menu.entryconfig('\u25A0', state='normal')
    n=100
    plot.run(n)
    for i in range(n):
        plot.addP(i*10,fn(i*10))

def stop(menu,plot):
    plot.stop
    menu.entryconfig('\u25B6', state='normal')
    menu.entryconfig('\u25A0', state='disabled')

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
menu.add_command(label='\u25B6', command=lambda: start(menu,plot))
#menu.entryconfig(1, fg='green')
menu.add_command(label='\u25A0', command=lambda: stop(menu,plot))
menu.entryconfig('\u25A0', state='disabled')

#start(menu,plot)

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, although I don't know how smart it is... Now I just continously plot xdata and ydata. Since I pass the reference, its updating any changes outside the plot class. However, I redraw the hole plot every time...

```
from tkinter import Frame
from matplotlib.pyplot import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
class LivePlotWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, xdata, ydata, xlabel='',ylabel='',logx=False,logy=False):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=1)     
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)   
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.xdata = xdata
        self.ydata = ydata
        self.xlabel = xlabel
        self.ylabel = ylabel
        self.logx = logx
        self.logy = logy
        self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.fig, self._update, interval=500)

    def _update(self,i):
        self.ax.cla()
        self.ax.set_xlabel(self.xlabel)
        self.ax.set_ylabel(self.ylabel)
        if self.logx:
            self.ax.set_xscale('log', nonposx='clip')
        if self.logy:
            self.ax.set_yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
        #if self.millikan:
        #    self.ax.plot(1/self.xdata,self.ydata)
        #else:
        self.ax.plot(self.xdata,self.ydata,'b.')  # update the data
        self.fig.tight_layout()
```